# php regex get all urls from mixed string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to get all urls from mixed string. 
My string:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000000.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000001.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000002.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000003.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000004.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
http://media.com/S1/HLS_VOD/26c2_1561/2500/segm000005.ts?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXTINF:10,
```

And my php code:

```
function getUrls($string) {
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    //return (array_reverse($matches[0]));
    return ($matches[0]);
```

}

```
$urls = getUrls($videourlget);
print_r($urls);
```

But it not return urls. I want to return only URL-s from string. Any idea?

Comment: Your string have text containing `href` but your regex depends on it.

Comment: i changed code. please look

Comment: @user3710676: Your regex currently matches newlines as well. Change the expression to `~https?://\S+~`. See [demo](https://eval.in/163547).